# help with probability (expectation) problem

Tags: probability, expected-value

any help with the question is appreciated!

the question is: Consider rolling a 5-sided die (a "D5") and counting the number of rolls up to and including the first "1" that appears. Imagine repeating that experiment 60 times and let  be the number of rolls taken on the -th attempt. Consider the average $A=\frac{1}{60}(X_1+..+X_{60})$ ask for the expectation E(A).

my attempt:

$E(A)=\frac{1}{60}(E(X_1)+..+E(X_{60}))=1/60((\frac{1}{5}\times1+\frac{1}{5}\times2+\frac{1}{5}\times3+\frac{1}{5}\times4+\frac{1}{5}\times5)+ E(X_2)+..+E(X_{60}))$

I know the attempt is very wrong... any hints are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is not clear.  What is $X_j$?  I assumed it was the number of tosses it takes to get the first $1$ on the $j^{th}$ experiment, so $E[X_j]=5$ for all $j$.  Is that correct or did you mean something else?

Comment: Research Geometric Probability distribution.

Comment: the sample average is an unbiased estimator of the true average so you just have to compute $E[X_1]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know that each $X_i$ is geometrically distributed, assuming the die fair, then $X_i\sim Geom(p)$, where $p=1/5$. It very known(and easy to show) that
$$E(X_i)=1/p$$

So you get that $E(X_i)=5$ for $1\le i\le 60$.